# MemoryError during Python list processing

Tags: python, list, memory, pickle

(Python version 2.6.5)

I have:

```
 boxes_with_sizes_added = [\
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0],\
 [785,500,200,787,502,202,1],\
 [400,500,600,404,504,604,2],\
 [100,200,300,108,208,308,3],\
 [50,60,70,51,61,71,0]\
 # several millions more...
 ]
```

...they are boxes in format: [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,rel_size]

and I have a 'chopping' method:

```
def cubic_breakdown(box,division_factor):
 if division_factor==1:
     return[box]
 elif division_factor>1:
     boxes_out=[]
     for k in range(division_factor):
         for j in range(division_factor):
             for i in range(division_factor):
                 boxes_out.append([\
                 (box[0]+((box[3]-box[0])/float(division_factor))*i),\
                 (box[1]+((box[4]-box[1])/float(division_factor))*j),\
                 (box[2]+((box[5]-box[2])/float(division_factor))*k),\
                 (box[0]+((box[3]-box[0])/float(division_factor))*(i+1)),\
                 (box[1]+((box[4]-box[1])/float(division_factor))*(j+1)),\
                 (box[2]+((box[5]-box[2])/float(division_factor))*(k+1)),\
                 box[6]\
                 ])
     return boxes_out
```

where basically a 'box' is 'chopped' into equal segments according to it's 'rel_size' and added to a list

```
 chopped_boxes=[]
 for box in boxes_with_sizes_added:
     for chopped_box in cubic_breakdown(box,2**box[6]):
         chopped_boxes.append(chopped_box)
```

When I try to process too many boxes, however, I get a 'MemoryError' at a certain point. What is the problem? Do I need to pickle my list or my list output? Thanks in advance!

Comment: jfyi, you don't need all these `\`s at the ends of lines. try it, it reads easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each item you create a list (`boxes_out`) with `6 * division_factor ** 3` elements, and you do so for every element of input. Even with `division_factor` = 2 you're increasing the size of your data 48 times. I don't know how much RAM you have but chances are it's not enough.

- Try using [`numpy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/) arrays; these are more compact and efficient, it might be enough to fit your data in RAM.
- Try using a database, e.g SQLite, and store your data on disk. Your algorithm looks sequential, you don't seem to need all the data in RAM at the same time.
- Get a bigger machine :) No, really, renting a high-memory EC2 instance is $0.5 to $1.5 a hour, and these come with plenty of RAM.

Comment: Thanks 9000...any advice on using SQLite? unfortunately numpy is not an option. How would writing to a database be implemented?

Comment: ...or using shelve? would anyone recommend this?